# Unicode error in python with forms (using Mechanize)

Tags: python, forms, unicode, mechanize

I am trying to read some forms in a webpage using Mechanize:

```
for f in br.forms():
     print f
```

and I obtain the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think I need convert some character butI don't knwo how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution:

```
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to a [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html),

```
for f in br.forms():
    print repr(f)
```

Comment: thank you for your proposal but I obtain following result: `<mechanize._form.HTMLForm instance at 0x10a0f8998>`. Normally I obtain a list with some details like this: `<TextControl(user=)>
  <PasswordControl(password=)>`

Comment: Provide more code and an example of what you are trying to print, so that others can run the code and test